# PCLCrypto MD5 HashAlgorithm

Tags: c#, hash, xamarin, md5, pcl-crypto

The value returned by `HashData` is not a Md5 hash example:

Hashing the "a" always return "`0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661`"

But this code always returns a different value.

```
private byte[] GetHash(string data)    
{
      IHashAlgorithmProvider algoProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Md5);
      byte [] dataTB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
      return algoProv.HashData(dataTB);
}
```

Comment: "but the code always returns a different value" - what do you mean? Note that you're just returning a byte array... how are you looking at the contents of that byte array? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: why the returned value of the code is not the same as the one i get from php md5( ) function ?

$x = md5("a");

Comment: Again, we don't know what you're doing with the returned value in order to compare it. You haven't told us what value *is* being returned. Without that information, it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the `MD5` algorithm from `PCLCrypto` and it worked as expected. Always printed "`0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661`"

```
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ByteArrayToHex((GetHash("a"))));
}

public static byte[] GetHash(string data)
{
    IHashAlgorithmProvider algoProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Md5);
    byte[] dataTB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    return algoProv.HashData(dataTB);
}

//Convert hash to hex
private static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] hash)
{
    var hex = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in hash)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

    return hex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: under which namespace can i find MD5Digest() ?

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea. An MD5 hash is *not* UTF-8-encoded text. The OP appears to want the result in hex, so `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` would be a better starting point.

Comment: The text was encoded before calculate the Hash. I've updated my answer. Please let me know what you think.